# Finding Annotations in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, annotations, intellij-idea, structural-search

I can easily find all mentions of some annotation in my project using SSR (structural search and replace). For example I have following spring based code:

```
class DashboardController {

  @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
  public void doDashboard() {
    [...]
  }
}
```

If I search by pattern `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping` than I will find my code. But what if I want to find methods annotated with parametrized annotation, so find only method with annotations `@RequestMapping` for "/dashboard" url?

I can simply search by `@RequestMapping("/dashboard")` string, but annotation can be written in several ways:

```
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
@RequestMapping(headers = "content-type=application/*", value = "/dashboard")
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Structural Search and Replace in IntelliJ IDEA 14. Copy the existing template *annotated methods* and add "/dashboard" as an argument to the annotation like so:

```
class $Class$ {
  @$Annotation$("/dashboard")
  $MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$);
}
```

You might also want to edit the $Annotation$ variable and give it the text/regexp "RequestMapping"
This should find all possible formats of the annotation (on methods only).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you search this :

```
@RequestMapping\(((.*?)value\s*=\s*)?"/dashboard"(.*?)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a text search for `@RequestMapping("/dashboard")`, its unlikely to give that many false positives.

Comment: There is several ways how this annotation can be written. For example, `@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = {RequestMethod.POST})` etc.

Comment: Then use a regex, something like `@RequestMapping(.*"/dashboard".*)`